# Windows desktop application that allows to visualize, edit, download, upload and convert GPX files?

Tags: gps, gpx, desktop-gis

I am looking for a simple application that will allow me to visualize GPX data, edit and create new GPX tracks, areas and points and download/upload GPX data to and from devices. This application should have worldwide vector maps and imagery background coverage.

[DNRGPS](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) is good but cumbersome and lacks the ability to visualize and visually edit and create data.

Google Earth Pro does not export to GPX.

Comment: QGIS & GPS Plugin? http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html

Comment: DNR GPS can be installed "into" ArcGIS as well as run as a separate program.  (We run it as a separate program.)  Does the former not work with your version of ArcGIS?  QGIS has a GPS Tools plugin that might do what you want.

Comment: http://www.gpstrackeditor.com/ ? QGIS with the GPS plugin? To and from devices is going to be somewhat tough, since that requires a driver for whatever specific device you're using. Manufacturers usually have their own software like Garmin's BaseCamp and the older MapSource. Note that if you haven't seen it, GPSBabel offers the ability to translate between formats, so GEP > KML > GPSBabel > GPX.

Comment: Try the free version of GPS trackmaker http://trackmaker.com/. It has probably some of the features you are after but not all.